# Sharepoint Online Shared Lookup Column Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Is it possible to create a list which is shared among subsites for the purposes of feeding a Lookup Column?  I am hoping to have 1 master company list which my sub sites can share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You need create a site column at the top level site which is a lookup to your list, then in your sub site you can add the site column into your custom list.

Use below link as reference for more information:

[How to Create a Cross-Site Lookup Site Column in SharePoint 2013?](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/how-to-create-cross-site-lookup-site-column-in-sharepoint.html?m=1).